# Using JS, jQuery ,html and css to build a web app with a api but having issue with button funcations

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a web search engine the uses the Giphy API... But what I am having problems with are the button function. I am builded button to change the format of the page and how many searches to show.... The Web works well but the button will not work I tried inline code and linking file nothing worked this is due Monday and I have been working all week on it... Please help! I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Here is some of the code...

`enter code here`

```js
function () {
    function giphySearchEngine(keyword, limit) {
      return fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${keyword}&api_key=h5nEbFf0nz3FmKUhFMFajDQpM6ew66XF&limit=${limit}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
    }
//h5nEbFf0nz3FmKUhFMFajDQpM6ew66XF// apikey 
//https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=h5nEbFf0nz3FmKUhFMFajDQpM6ew66XF&q=&limit=18&offset=0&rating=G&lang=en
  
    function images (img) {
      let $div = $('<div class="row"></div>');
      $('<div class="col"></div>').append(img).appendTo($div);
      $('#show').append($div)
    }
  
    function resultLoad(img) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        img.onload = resolve;
      });
    }
  //search field text box 
    (function listenOnFormSubmit() {
      $('#searchForm').submit(async (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
  
        let $input = $('#searchInput');
  
        main($input.val());
      });
       
     
    })
    ();
    async function main(keyword) {
      const result = await giphySearchEngine(keyword);
      $('#show').html('');    
      
      let promises = [];
      result.data.forEach(gif => {
         let img = new Image();
         img.src = gif.images.original.url;
         promises.push(resultLoad(img));
        images (img);
      });
       //Gif limit buttons
     $('#btn6').on('click', function() {
        console.log('Get me 6 results!');
        giphySearchEngine(keyword, 6);
      });
    
      $('#btn12').on('click', function() {
        console.log('Get me 12 results!');
        giphySearchEngine(keyword, 12);
      });
    
      $('#btn18').on('click', function() {
        console.log('Get me 18 results!');
        giphySearchEngine(keyword, 18);
      });
    }
  })();
```

```css
/* font */
body{
font-family:
'Bangers', cursive;
color:#393e46;
}
/* color layout */
.background{
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
div.input-group {
    width: auto;
}

  /* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
      flex: 50%;
      max-width: 50%;
    }
  }
  
  /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col {
      flex: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  

footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #393e46;
    text-align: right;
   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://colorhunt.co/palette/130807">
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Giphy Web search engine</title>
    <style>

      /* css for grid */
    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      
      .header {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 32px;
      }
      
      .row {
        
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 0 4px;
      }
      
      /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
      .col {
       
        flex: 50%;
        padding: 0 4px;
      }
      
      .col img{
        margin-top: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      
      /* Style the buttons */
      .btn-group  { 
          display: block; text-align: right; 
        }
        .btn-group.btn{ 
            float: none;
        }
    
      .btn {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      
      .btn:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      
      .btn.active {
        background-color: #666;
        color: white;
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><img src ="images/PoweredBy_100px_Badge.gif"alt="" width="75" height="75" >Giphy</h1>
   

    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
      <h1>Giphy Image Changer</h1>
      <p>Click on the buttons to change the giphy view.</p>
      <button class="btn" onclick="one()">1</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="two()">2</button>
      <button class="btn active" onclick="four()">4</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <form id="searchForm">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 mx-md-3">
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" class="form-control" id='searchInput'placeholder="Enter Gif Search" aria-label="Enter Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"><svg class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 011.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 100-11 5.5 5.5 0 000 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 11-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0113 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
        </svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-group mr-3 mx-md-3"  role="group" aria-label="Second group">
      <button type="button" id ='btn6'  class="btn">6</button>
      <button type="button" id ='btn12' class="btn">12</button>
      <button type="button" id ='btn18' class="btn">18</button>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id ="show" class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      

  <footer>
    <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
      <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">Copyrights: Jose Rodriguez®</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Contact info: j.rodriguez48@yahoo.com</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><img src="images/PoweredBy_200px-White_HorizText.png"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
    
  
  
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script>
      // Get the elements with class="col"
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
  
  // Declare a loop variable
  let i;
  
  // Full-width images
  function one() {
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.flex = "100%";
      console.log(one);
    }
  }
  
  // Two images side by side
  function two() {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.flex = "50%";
    }
  }
  
  // Four images side by side
  function four() {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.flex = "25%";
    }
  }
  
  // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
  let header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
  let btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");

  for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
  </script>
    

  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Have you done basic logging, is your `giphySearchEngine` function working to do what you think it does?

Comment: yes I have the buttons shows up in the console but won't work on the webpage.

Comment: Calling giphySearchEngine(keyword, 6); does not alter the original result.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Your current implementation doesn't read results

```
     $('#btn6').on('click', async function() {
        console.log('Get me 6 results!');
        const newResults = await giphySearchEngine(keyword, 6);
        // Do nothing with new results.

      });
```

You have only resolved the first search promise.
You need to resolve each search request and loop through the results.

Try and encapsulate it in a function

```
async function main(keyword) {
    async function search(keyword) {
      const result = await giphySearchEngine(keyword);
      $('#show').html('');    

      let promises = [];
      result.data.forEach(gif => {
         let img = new Image();
         img.src = gif.images.original.url;
         promises.push(resultLoad(img));
        images (img);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand how would looping through the result help fix the button functions? my search function produces my result array[ ] and shows all the images.  maybe you can show an example or a link I can read.  thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @userJR Javascript executes top down. So for each main() call. Results gets looped once. Consecutive calls to giphySearchEgine() are ignored.
Because you haven't read or done anything with the results.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help, but i just couldn't get it to work so I had to remove the buttons... Thank you for trying I guess I am just not there yet.